# What font is used in the following image? (2014 Brazil)

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

What font is used in the following image?

[image: font]

Answer (score 3):

That's [Bebas Neue](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bebas-neue) with a distortion effect.

[image]

[image]